# Error en la propiedad o ruta de la clase de un archivo en java

Tags: java, java-8, compilar, variables-de-configuración

Buenas tardes compañeros,

Estoy viendo un curso de Java Basico, para aprender un poco sobre ese lenguaje de programacion, Actualmente estoy presentando un problema, le cambie por error la propiedad de los archivos que se generan al realizar el comando javac XXXX.java ya que los archivos que se guardaban .TXT estaban en un formato tipo Explotador y al ejecutarlos se abria con cualquier explorador de internet y no en un block de notas.

Ahora resolví el problema cambiando la extensión de los archivos en TXT y al momento de abrir el Archivo que me da al ejecutar el Javac XXXX.java ejecutando el XXXX.java en mi CMD, me indica lo siguiente:

```
public class Prueba{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("esto es una prueba");
    }
}

Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXXX\Escritorio\linkedin\java\XXXX.java
```

Les envio print de pantalla para que puedan validar el error, ya lo he desintalado e instalaado varias veces, acomodado las variables de entorno y aun sigo presentando el mismo error y antes no me pasaba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les muestro el error en pantalla, el nombre de la extension de como guarda el archivo y las propiedades del archivo guardado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El archivo .java es el código fuente, una vez compilado, se debe ejecutar el .class
Para compilar, tal como lo hiciste debes poner:

```
javac NombreClase.java
```

Eso te genera el .class (Si no existen errores al compilar). Una vez compilado, debes ejecutarlo con:

```
java NombreClase
```

Nótese que no se pone el '.class'

Con eso no deberías tener problemas...

Answer (score 0):

Estaba aplicando el comando mal es java XXXX, no XXXX.java

Disculpen el hilo de respuesta

Saludos!